# If and else statements wont work in this small program, help please :)

Tags: c

Compiler errors:

```
pythagoras.c: In function ‘main’:
pythagoras.c:22:4: fejl: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
pythagoras.c:29:5: fejl: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
  double a, b, c;
  double secondside1, secondside2, secondside3;
char Scanres;
printf("Hvilken side vil du finde? a, b eller c?\n");
Scanres = scanf("%c", &Scanres);
secondside1 = a * a;
secondside2 = b * b;
secondside3 = c * c;

    if(Scanres = c);

    printf("Indtast værdierne af a og b\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &b);
    c = sqrt(secondside1 + secondside2);
        printf("c er %f", c);

        else if(Scanres = b);

        printf("Indtast værdierne af a og c\n");
        scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &c);
        b = sqrt(secondside3 - secondside2);
        printf("b er %f\n", b);

            else(Scanres = a);

            printf("Indtast værdierne af b og c\n");
            scanf("%lf%lf", &b, &c);
            a = sqrt(secondside3 - secondside1);
            printf("a er %lf", a);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have  semi-colon after the first if.

Comment: ...and also after the `else if`

Comment: Have you come from a python world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison operator in C is `==`. With a single `=` you are doing assignment.

Also, having a semicolon after the `if()` makes it execute an empty statement, rather than the code path you thought.

Note that indentation is free in C, it carries no meaning so the compiler won't warn you if it seems non-sensical.

Further, this:

```
Scanres = scanf("%c", &Scanres);
```

doesn't make a lot of sense. The `scanf()` function will write the character it read into `Scanres`, but then you will overwrite that value by storing the return value of `scanf()` (which is the number of conversions it made) into the same variable.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies, i'll try and do what you all said :)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of `if` statement is :

```
if (expr) statement;
```

`statement` could be an instruction block, so you have to add brackets.

```
int main(void)
{
    double a, b, c;
    double secondside1, secondside2, secondside3;
    char Scanres;
    printf("Hvilken side vil du finde? a, b eller c?\n");
    Scanres = scanf("%c", &Scanres);
    secondside1 = a * a;
    secondside2 = b * b;
    secondside3 = c * c;

    if (Scanres == c) 
    {
        printf("Indtast værdierne af a og b\n");
        scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &b);
        c = sqrt(secondside1 + secondside2);
        printf("c er %f", c);
    }
    else if (Scanres == b) 
    {

        printf("Indtast værdierne af a og c\n");
        scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &c);
        b = sqrt(secondside3 - secondside2);
        printf("b er %f\n", b);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Indtast værdierne af b og c\n");
        scanf("%lf%lf", &b, &c);
        a = sqrt(secondside3 - secondside1);
        printf("a er %lf", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- `else` doesn't need an expression.
- You don't use the good operator. `==` is the comparaison operator, not `=`.
- `a`, `b` and `c` are not initialized.
- `scanf` return value is the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, not the read values.

You should read the basis.

Answer (score 1):

Hey remove the semi colons

```
if(Scanres = c);
```

And use brackets like

```
if ( statement)
{
  code
}
else if ( statement )
{
code
}
else
{
code
}
```

This should solve it. Please make sure that you correctly input the variables defined "a" "b" and "c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
  double a, b, c;
  a = 10 ;
  b = 12 ;
  c = 15 ;

  // Here you must make it that the user inputs the 3 variables ; I have entered them manually first 
  // Use scanf or fgets to input the 3 variables. And there you go !!

  double secondside1, secondside2, secondside3;
  char Scanres;
  printf("Hvilken side vil du finde? a, b eller c?\n");
  Scanres = scanf("%c", &Scanres);
  secondside1 = a * a;
  secondside2 = b * b;
  secondside3 = c * c;

    if(Scanres == c)
    {
    printf("Indtast værdierne af a og b\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &b);
    c = sqrt(secondside1 + secondside2);
        printf("c er %f", c);
    }
        else if(Scanres == b)
    {
        printf("Indtast værdierne af a og c\n");
        scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &c);
        b = sqrt(secondside3 - secondside2);
        printf("b er %f\n", b);
    }
    else if(Scanres == a)
    {
            printf("Indtast værdierne af b og c\n");
            scanf("%lf%lf", &b, &c);
            a = sqrt(secondside3 - secondside1);
            printf("a er %lf", a);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I editted what you  guys told me and the compiler doesnt give me an error now, but when i either write a b or c, the wrong calculation come up

Comment: Ofc here it is, i cant get it to work proberbly, when i try to find b and c it asks for b and c sites and so on. and i would assume its my scanf thats funky.

Comment: Oh and it seems like i cant copy my code in here anymore, its too long for the comment thingy :x

Comment: Ok here is what i will do !
I will edit your code then re post under my main comment.

Comment: Hmm running the code you gave me doesnt send me to if its a b or c or am i missing the point here?

Comment: I did not include it ^^ I said that in the comment.
Use fgets(a); fgets(b); fgets(c) underneath my comment.

Comment: Ah, I havent learned the fgets(a) and so on yet, but its same princip as scanf? Btw now i have them all working, though when i do the a and b, the calculation is wrong.

Comment: Yes i guess it should be the same as scanf. As for the wrong calculation can you please let me know what you are doing to i can see where i can help ??

Comment: My c works fine, but when trying to calculate the a and b i get the result nan for some reason hehe   else if(Scanres == 'b')
   {
   printf("Indtast værdierne af a og c\n");
   scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &c);
   double secondside1 = (a*a), secondside2 = (b*b), secondside3 = (c*c);
   b = sqrt(secondside3 - secondside2);
   printf("b er %lf", b); hard to make it look good here in add comment, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your if/else syntax is all wonky, you need to use curly braces `{}` to identify the blocks associated with each condition.  Additionally, use the `==` operator to test for equality:

```c
if (Scanres == c) { /* Start the block for this case */
  /* ... */
} else if (Scanres == b) { /* Here's how you do an "else if" block. */
  /* ... */
```

Comment: Can be closed, thanks for everyone and their replies, i figured the last things out :)